# Get Taxonomy name from “registered_taxonomy” hook

Tags: taxonomy, actions

I am using add_action to run a function after a taxonomy is created. Everything works but I can’t figure out how to grab the taxonomy name. I figured $args->name would be the way to go but it is not working, it is not returning anything.

```
function test( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ) {
    $catname = $args->name;
}

add_action( 'registered_taxonomy', 'test',10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

`$args` is an array, not an object:

```
function test( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ) {
    echo $args['name'];
}
add_action( 'registered_taxonomy', 'test', 10, 3 );
```

**EDIT**

Using the `create_term` action:

```
function my_create( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ){
    $term = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy );
    echo $term->name;
}
add_action( 'create_term', 'my_create', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now getting "category" back as the name where I need the actual term name back.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong action. You want term creation, not taxonomy registration.

Comment: So the reason I want taxonomy registration is because I want to perform a function whenever a new category is created. It is triggering when I want it to, I just need access to the name of the category that was created. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That's not what taxonomy registration is. "Category" is a *taxonomy*, and that taxonomy contains *terms*. You create a taxonomy once, you add as many terms as you want to that taxonomy. The action you want is when those terms are created. See my edit above.

Comment: I understand now where I went wrong, thanks a lot. I made the changes and it works great.